# How disallow the updating of certain fields using firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I had a specific user role which is only allowed to update certain fields.

This is what my firestore rules look like for this particular case:

```
    function isRoleUser () {
      return request.auth.token.role == 'user'
    }

    function isRoleAdmin () {
      return request.auth.token.role == 'admin'
    }

...

allow update: if signedIn() && (
        (
          isRoleUser() && (
            request.auth.uid == resource.id &&
            !(request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(['disallowed1', 'disallowed2', 'disallowed3']))
          )
        ) || (
          isRoleAdmin()
        )
      );
```

The issue I am having is even when I am NOT updating the disallowed fields, I still get the message saying the user has insufficient permissions.

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

However if I remove the following line:

> !(request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(['disallowed1', 'disallowed2',
>   'disallowed3']))

I can update the user as expected, but obviously I will lose the limitations I want to impose. Is there something wrong with my rules? If so, how can I prevent the user from updating the listed fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.resource.data.keys()` always contains the entire set of fields that describe the document if the write would succeed.  It does not just contain the fields that are going to change.  So, if you want to restrict write access to certain fields, you need to check if the contents of that field changed in your rules.  You will have to do this individually for each field, for the role in question.

So, for field foo:

```
request.resource.data.foo != resource.data.foo
```

Comment: I often use this little helper function in my rules: `function isUnmodified(key) {
      return request.resource.data[key] == resource.data[key]
    }`